# PowerShell - Read data from a csv file, compare data from a specific column and write the results to a new file

Tags: powershell, csv, comparison

I am new to PowerShell and would like to seek your inputs. I have an "Incoming" csv file from which I need to create an "Outgoing" csv file by doing the following.

1. Copy the contents the "Incoming" file to the "Outgoing" file as-is.
2. Loop through the column "ID" and for each unique ID, copy the row and append the "Outgoing" file.

Incoming File Sample:

[image: Incoming File Sample]

Outgoing File Sample:

[image: Outgoing File Sample]

Is this doable from PowerShell?

Comment: Are the real `ID` values supposed to be unique? There are duplicates in both file samples. The blue text suggests you only want the first instance of each `ID` copied?

Comment: No, "ID" values can be duplicate. You are correct - only the first instance of each ID needs to be copied.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you described:

```
# Import your data
$incoming = Import-Csv 'c:\folder\incoming.csv'

# 1. Copy Incoming onto Outgoing:
$incoming | Select *,NewColumn | Export-Csv C:\temp\test.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation

# 2. Append the first Incoming row with a unique ID to Outgoing:
$incoming | 
  Group-Object ID |        ## Group rows by ID
  Foreach {$_.Group[0]} |  ## Select first row per ID
  Select *,@{l='NewColumn';e={"Added via script"}} |  ## Add column
  Export-Csv 'c:\folder\outgoing.csv' -Append -NoTypeInformation

# example incoming:
ID  Invoice Paid
--  ------- ----
100 100     150 
100 50      150 
101 200     200 
102 500     850 
102 250     850 
102 100     850 

# creates this outgoing (assuming EMPTY outgoing file to start with):
ID  Invoice Paid NewColumn       
--  ------- ---- ---------       
100 100     150                  
100 50      150                  
101 200     200                  
102 500     850                  
102 250     850                  
102 100     850                  
100 100     150  Added via script
101 200     200  Added via script
102 500     850  Added via script
```

Note that the `Outgoing` csv file **must** already have the `NewColumn` field added for `-Append` to work properly if using an existing file. Otherwise your new column will not be exported.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks so much. One more question - is it possible to add a static text (like "Added via script") to the newly added rows to indicate that the original file didn't have them.

Comment: @John it will stop being a valid csv file,  but you could always just add `"Added via script" | Out-File 'c:\folder\outgoing.csv' -Append` between steps. Or do you mean like an additional column?

Comment: yes I meant an additional column.

Comment: @John I've edited my answer.